# What is the correct method for writing .format() method in Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a code with .format() interpolation method but getting a same error while printing the stmt.
Below is the error.
Thanks for the help.

```
      1 
      2 txt1 = "My name is {}, I'm {}".format('john','12')
----> 3 print(txt1)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have probably shadowed `print` earlier in your code by writing something like `print =  "some string"`.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Restart your interpreter and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: If this is part of a script, change the name of the offending variable. If you're in an interactive session, you can `del print` to give it its original meaning back.

Comment: To be clear, there is nothing wrong with the way you used `format`; the problem is a previous assignment to the name `print`.

Answer (score -1):

it's easier to use another way of string formatting, like:

```
name = 'john'
age = 12
text = f"My name is {name}, I'm {12}"
```

Comment: This isn't relevant; it won't fix the problem the user is observing.